# My program won't print my results

Tags: c, unix, printing, printf, octal

I recently wrote a brute force program to turn the octal data from permissions in Unix into the human readable form (e.g. `755 -> rwxr-xr-x`) However whenever I run my program called `myperm` I don't get a result (e.g. `./myperm 755 -> nothing`) and I'm not quite sure why can anyone help with this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
       if (argv[1] == "777")
       {
          printf("rwxrwxrwx");
       }

       else if (argv[1] == "755")
       {
            printf("rwxr-xr-x");
       }

       else if (argv[1] == "750")
       {
            printf("rwxr-x---");
       }
       else if (argv[1] == "700")
       {
            printf("rwxr-x---");
       }
       else if (argv[1] == "666")
       {
            printf("rw-rw-rw");
       }
       else if (argv[1] == "664")
       {
            printf("rw-rw-r--");
       }
       else if (argv[1] == "640")
       {
            printf("rw-r-----");
       }
       else if (argv[1] == "600")
       {
            printf("rw-------");
       }
       else if (argv[1] == "400")
       {
            printf("r--------");
       }
return (0);

}
```

Comment: `(argv[1] == "777")` -> `(strcmp(argv[1],"777") == 0)`

Comment: `"..."` evaluates to a character array, you need to compare characters, not addresses.

Comment: Sidenote: your code is terribly poor: consider to write a function that translates an octal digit to say "rwx" (for 7) otherwise your code will be painfully long and error prone to cover all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing strings in C doesn't work like this, you have to use `strcmp`

Instead of doing `if (argv[1] == "XXX")`, you should do `if (strcmp(argv[1], "XXX") == 0)`

[Read on here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004237/2266261)

Comment: Since you already found the proper canonical duplicate, just flag/close vote as duplicate rather then posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
argv[1] == "755"
```

is *not* how you compare strings in C, you need to use:

```
strcmp (argv[1], "755") == 0
```

In any case, this "brute force" method is both totally unnecessary and unreliable (missing possibilities, only nine of the 512 possibilities are handled, even *without* taking into account setuid and setgid bits and so on).

You would be better off having a function to evaluate *one* octal digit, such as:

```
static const char * permXlat (char octal) {
    switch (octal) {
        case '0' : return "---";
        case '1' : return "--x";
        case '2' : return "-w-";
        case '3' : return "-wx";
        case '4' : return "r--";
        case '5' : return "r-x";
        case '6' : return "rw-";
    }
    return "rwx";
}
```

and then processing the argument one character at a time:

```
printf ("%s%s%s\n",
    permXlat (argv[1][0]),
    permXlat (argv[1][1]),
    permXlat (argv[1][2]));
```

adding whatever sanity checking you think is necessary (argument list size, character values and so on).

Comment: The smug version would be `ch -= '0'; for(uint8_t i = 0; i<3; i++) { result[i] = ch&1<<2-i?i["rwx"]:'-'; } result[3] = '\0';`. This version has... no advantage what-so-ever. But it looks cool.